# Does VPN from Android App tunnel network traffic from Chrome on Chromebook?

Tags: android, vpn, chromebook, android-vpn-service, androidappsonchromeos

I am working on a VPN app (uses VpnService) which has been working on Android devices. When I run it on a Chromebook, the VpnService appears to be started correctly based on the logs. Additionally, the OS acknowledges that my app is running a VPN in the status bar and on the device's network settings page.

However, it does not appear to be tunneling network traffic from Chrome (which was the main goal of using it on a Chromebook). After doing some research online, I can't seem to get a clear answer on whether that is expected or not. Some articles and posts seem to suggest that VPN from an Android app works for all network traffic on the device and some suggest that you need a Chrome OS app to do so.

Was wondering if anyone has any experience with using Android apps for VPN on a Chromebook and if they can work for tunneling network traffic from Chrome on a Chromebook?